# If selected level of category is lower than configured level then show lowest level

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have following table

**Category**

```
Category Id     |    Name     | Parent Id   |   Category Level
-------------------------------------------------------------
     1          |   Vehicle   |    Null     |         1
     2          |     Car     |     1       |         2
     3          |    Sedan    |     2       |         3
     4          |   Computer  |    Null     |         1
     5          |    Laptop   |     4       |         2
     6          |    Gaming   |     5       |         3
     7          |   Alienware |     6       |         4
```

Level of category is decided based on Category hierarchy.

Here in Category table we have 2 main categories Vehicle and Computer

If I have selected the Level 4 then I want records on Category Level 4 if there is no level 4 in that category then I want the records on the lowest level. So in the output we'll get Sedan(Lowest in Vehicle) and Alienware(Level 4).

Can anyone suggest how can I achieve this in Power BI.

Comment: Category Level order is always as shown now? Or another level for vehicle can be there at the end with Category Id 8?

Comment: Yes there can be another level for vehicle added into the table afterwards.

Comment: Is there any maximum level? or any level can be there for a category?

Comment: Right now it can be any level but it won't exceed level 4.

Comment: Is this really an <sql> _language_ related question?

Comment: Not really, my client wants to see the lowest level of categories configured if user wants to see level 4 categories and in some 'main categories' there isn't any level 4 then in that case the lowest level of those 'main categories' should be returned and by 'main category' I mean categories whose level is 1.

Answer (score 0):

**Considering Highest level: 4, let your table Category contains records as below**

[image]

Now create a new table **Category_new** in **Power Query Editor** using this below code-

```
let
    Source = Category,
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Category Id", Int64.Type}, {"Name", type text}, {"Parent Id", Int64.Type}, {"Category Level", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Category Level", "Category Id", "Name", "Parent Id"}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Reordered Columns", {"Parent Id"}, #"Reordered Columns", {"Category Id"}, "Reordered Columns", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Reordered Columns" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Reordered Columns", {"Parent Id"}, {"Reordered Columns.Parent Id"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Reordered Columns",{{"Reordered Columns.Parent Id", "Parent Id 2"}}),
    #"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Renamed Columns", {"Parent Id 2"}, #"Renamed Columns", {"Category Id"}, "Renamed Columns", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Renamed Columns" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "Renamed Columns", {"Parent Id"}, {"Renamed Columns.Parent Id"}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Renamed Columns",{{"Renamed Columns.Parent Id", "Parent Id 3"}}),
    #"Merged Queries2" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Parent Id 3"}, #"Renamed Columns1", {"Category Id"}, "Renamed Columns1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Renamed Columns1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries2", "Renamed Columns1", {"Parent Id"}, {"Renamed Columns1.Parent Id"}),
    #"Renamed Columns2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Renamed Columns1",{{"Renamed Columns1.Parent Id", "Parent Id 4"}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns2", "Custom", each List.Min({[Category Id], [Parent Id], [Parent Id 2], [Parent Id 3], [Parent Id 4]})),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each List.Max({[Category Id], [Parent Id], [Parent Id 2], [Parent Id 3], [Parent Id 4]})),
    #"Renamed Columns3" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Custom1",{{"Custom", "Root Category"}, {"Custom.1", "Max Level"}}),
    #"Merged Queries3" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Renamed Columns3", {"Root Category"}, #"Renamed Columns3", {"Category Id"}, "Renamed Columns3", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Renamed Columns3" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries3", "Renamed Columns3", {"Name"}, {"Renamed Columns3.Name"}),
    #"Renamed Columns4" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Renamed Columns3",{{"Renamed Columns3.Name", "Root Category Name"}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Renamed Columns4", {"Root Category Name"}, {{"max_level", each List.Max([Max Level]), type nullable number}}),
    #"Merged Queries4" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Grouped Rows", {"max_level"}, Category, {"Category Id"}, "Category", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Category" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries4", "Category", {"Name"}, {"Category.Name"}),
    #"Renamed Columns5" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Category",{{"Category.Name", "lowest in category"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns5"
```

Here is your final output-

[image]

Comment: Sorry I didn't mentioned earlier, I'm using direct query mode so I can't edit tables using power query editor and I have to use slicer to filter this data dynamically.

Comment: Then pick your required output using Query.

Comment: Can you help me with that query?

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: I'm using SQL server.